# Prove limit exists in $L^1$ and poinwise

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove $L^1$ is complete. Need help with this step:

Consider a sequence $f_k$ in $L^1$ with 
$$\|{f_{{k+1}}-f_{k}\|}_{L^1} <2^{-k}$$
Define 
$$g_k(x)=\sum^k_j|f_j(x)-f_{j+1}(x)|$$
show limit $g_k$ exists in  $L^1$ and point wise.
$\lim_k g_k$ is in $L^1$, since
 $$\int |\lim_k g_k(x)|\mu(dx)\leq \int \lim_k \sum_j^k |f_{j+1}(x)-f_j(x)|\mu(dx)=\lim_k\int \sum_j^k |f_{j+1}(x)-f_j(x)|\mu(dx)$$ 
since Beppo Levi $\iff$ finite additivity of the integral and using monotone convergence, so:
$$\int \lim_k g_k(x)\mu(dx) \leq \lim_k 2^{-k} <\infty  \Rightarrow \lim_kg_k\in L^1.$$

How do I show the point wise limit exists?

Comment: Try Markov inequality. Also, $g_k$ should be $f_k$ i imagine

Comment: I had forgotten to define $g_k$ sorry.

Comment: Are you interested in the pointwise limit of $g_k$? This exists just because of the monotonicity

Comment: Yea. I want to show  $g_k \to g_\infty$ exists as well.

Comment: The almost everywhere limit of $f_k$ exists up to a subsequence because they converge in measure (by Markov inequality).

Comment: For every $x$, $g_k(x)$ is increasing in $k$, so it has a limit

Comment: Does beppo levi say the limit exist? or just if it exists its measurable and int of supremum is supremum  of integral?

Comment: What I'm saying is just that $\lim_{k\to\infty} g_k(x)\in[0,\infty]$ exists for every $x$ because it is an increasing sequence.

Comment: Because its increasing and bounded? Or are we allowing the limit to be $\infty$?

Comment: It isn't necessarily bounded. We are allowing $\infty$, as I wrote before.

Comment: Try to find an example $(f_k)$ where you get $\lim_k g_k(0)=\infty$.

Comment: How do I show the $L^1$ limit of $g_k$ exists here?

Comment: This a different question. For this one you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral

Comment: I am even more confused now. To show convergence in L^p I always used completeness. But now that I have to show completeness I feel like I can't do anything

Comment: You do use completeness of the scalar field.

Comment: $g_k$ converge pointwise and in $L^1$ because they are monotone in $k$

Comment: What you also get is that $f_k$ converge in measure, hence pointwise, hence you can define a limiting function $f$, and then you verify that $f_k\to f$ in $L^1$

Comment: @Federico I just don't understand why that can be true. Since when does monotonicty alone give convergence? It's true when we are dealing with the limit of an integral but not any sequence. Any literature you can point me to for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this lemma will clear things up: suppose that $X$ is a measure space and $1 ≤ p < ∞$. If $\{g_k ∈ Lp(X) : k ∈ N\}$ is a sequence of $Lp$-functions such that $\sum \|g_k\|<∞$,
then there exists a function $f ∈ L_p(X)$ such that $\sum g_k=f.$

The proof goes as follows:

Define $h_n=\sum^n |g_k|;\ h=\sum^n |g_k|$. Then, $h_n\uparrow h$ (in theory, the sum may be infinite.) In any case, the monotone convergence theorem gives $\int h^p=\lim \int h_n^p.$

On the other hand, Minkowski's inequality says $\|h_n\|_p\le \sum^n\|g_k\|_p\le \sum \|g_k\|_p<\infty$ (the last inequality holds by assumption.) Therefore, $h\in L_p(X).$

So, in fact, $h$ is finite a.e. and this implies that $\sum^n g_k$ converges absolutely a.e. to a function $f\in L_p(X)$ (because $|f|<h\in L_p(X).)$

Now, the dominated convergence theorem applies to show that the sum also converges to $f$ in $L_p(X)$, for  $\left | f-\sum^{n} g_k\right |^{p}\le (2h)^{p}$